# Radio button returning undefined when not shown

Tags: coldfusion

I have a question involving two radio buttons: Yes and No. If "no" is selected, nothing happens. If "yes" is selected, another question with two radio buttons appear, also with Yes or No. The problem is that when "no" is selected it does not present the other questions, which makes this error then appear when submitted"

> Element Mailincare_1 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope.

**Form Code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clearfix">
   <label for="Mailto_1">Mail to address other than mailing address listed above?</label>
   <cfoutput><input type="radio" value="Yes" name="Mailto_1" id="Mailto_1" required="yes" /></cfoutput>
   <label for="Mailto_1">Yes</label>
   <cfoutput><input type="radio" value="No" name="Mailto_1" id="noMailto_1" /></cfoutput>
   <label for="noMailto_1">No</label>
   <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
   <label for="Mailto_1" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
</div>

<!---If Yes (mailto) is selected Dropdown information appears (if none clear text from textboxes)--->
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('change', 'input[name=Mailto_1]', function() {

       var value = $(this).val();

       if (value == "Yes") {
           $('#Mailincare').show();
       } else {
           $('#Mailincare').hide();
           $("#Mailincare_1").prop('checked', false);
           $("#noMailincare_1").prop('checked', false);
           $("#cfirstname_1").val("");
           $("#div2 > .clearfix input:text").val("");
           $('#div1').hide();
           $('#div2').hide();
       }
   });


</script>
<div id="Mailincare" class="clearfix" style="display:none">
   <label for="Mailincare_1">Mail in care of someone else's name?</label>
   <cfoutput><input type="radio" value="Yes" name="Mailincare_1" id="Mailincare_1"/></cfoutput>
   <label for="Mailincare_1">Yes</label>
   <cfoutput><input type="radio" value="No" name="Mailincare_1" id="noMailincare_1" /></cfoutput>
   <label for="noMailincare_1">No</label>
   <!---Label is here for placement of error message--->
   <label for="Mailincare_1" class="error" style="display:none;">Please choose one.</label>
</div>
```

Sorry for posting all this, but I just wanted to show how the sessions are being set up.

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "submit")>
     <cfset errors = []>
     <cfif not arrayLen(errors)>
        <cfloop index="Add" from="1" to="#session.checkout.quantity.pcount#" step="1">
            <cfset session.checkout.info["firstname_#Add#"]=form["firstname_#Add#"]>
                ... 
                <cfif Add EQ 1>
                    <cfset session.checkout.info["Mailto_#Add#"]=form["Mailto_#Add#"]>
                       <cfset session.checkout.info["Mailincare_#Add#"]=form["Mailincare_#Add#"]>
                    ...
                </cfif>
                ....
            </cfloop>
            <cflocation url="vehicleInfo.cfm" addToken="false">
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You could just manually set one of those radio buttons to 'checked'. If they aren't shown, it is assumed the answer to the question has to be (or is implied to always be) "yes" or "no", right? If they ARE loaded, then the user can simply click whichever one applies. It's quick and dirty but it'd solve your problem without extra programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to deal with this.  In no particular order, here are three of them

- check for the existence of the form field before doing anything with
  it.
- Use `<cfparam>` to ensure the field always exists
- Add a hidden form field with the same name to your form.  When you
  submit the form, use ListLast to get the value of the radio button if
  it was submitted.